# NSClassFromString - doesn't work

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i'm trying to use dynamic typing in Obj-C, i've got following code and errors:

[image]

For me it seems good, but it don't want to work, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not actually creating a new instance (just retrieving one), there is no need for this. This is sufficient:

```
// If we don't know the exact class of the cell, type it with the common superclass of all cells
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"rssItemCell"];
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you're creating cellClass at runtime, the compiler doesn't know about it so it can't compile that code.

This would work :

```
Class cellClass = NSClassFromString(@"CustomCell");
UITableViewCell *cell; // You could just id here as well if you wanted but you now that CustomCell is definitely a type of UITableViewCell
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"rssItemCell"];
```

However, why don't you just do this?

```
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"rssItemCell"];
```

Comment: becouse it will not always be CustomCell, it must be not fixed, thanks for help , i will test your solution

Answer (score 0):

You can't use your variable cellClass as a type, it's an object.

In this case you have to use an id object or UITableViewCell. Something like this :

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"rssItemCell"];
```

or

```
id cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"rssItemCell"];
```